# How to serialize more than one fields into one variable in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm getting two fields as an array image and its color, HTML is:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="file" name="images[source][]" class="form-control input-lg">
    <input type="text" name="images[color][]" class="form-control input-lg">
</div>
```

And PHP is

```
$images=array();
if(isset($_FILES['images']) && sizeof($_FILES['images']['source']) > 0)
{
    foreach($_FILES['images']['source'] as $index=>$source)
    {
        if(!empty($source) && !empty($_POST['images']['color'][$index]))
        {
            $images[]=array('source'=>$source,'color'=>$_POST['images']['color'][$index]);
        }
    }
    if(sizeof($images) > 0)
    {
        $data['images']=$N['images']=serialize($images);
    }

}
```

But when on click submit button there is no any result for image source but image color displaying...
Any help will be appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

Hey buddy you are missing the name key in the `$_FILES` object. You need to check on that as well. Here is the updated code.

```
<?php 
$images=array();
if(isset($_FILES['images']) && sizeof($_FILES['images']['name']['source']) > 0) 
    // name is present before source, you need to add that part
{
    foreach($_FILES['images']['name']['source'] as $index=>$source)
    {
        if(!empty($source) && !empty($_POST['images']['color'][$index]))
        {
            $images[]=array('source'=>$source,'color'=>$_POST['images']['color'][$index]);
        }
    }
    if(sizeof($images) > 0)
    {
        $data['images']=$N['images']=serialize($images);
    }
} ?>
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: great answer but my code working now without name just changing input name as images[] and for color it is color[]

Comment: Well I thought you needed to capture the images and colors in same array, so i framed my solution accordingly. If you would've mentioned something like the flexibilty to capture the images and colors in separate array I would have suggested that earlier as well.Glad you solved your bug!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help guys my code is now working with
HTML:

`<input type="file" name="images[]">
<input type="text" name="color[]">`

PHP:

```
$array_serialize = array();
        if (!empty($_FILES['image'])){
            $files = $_FILES['image'];
            $images = $files['name'];
            foreach($images as $index=>$image)
            {
                if(!empty($image) && !empty($_POST['color'][$index]))
                {
                    $array_serialize[]=array('image'=>$image,'color'=>$_POST['color'][$index]);
                }
            }
            $N['images'] = serialize($array_serialize);
        }
```